# Eclipse-Juno Undo/Redo Enable?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Quick question, how do I enable Undo/Redo in Eclipse-Juno?

I am using:

```
Eclipse for Mobile Developers
Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800
```

Even just typing some random text into the editor, Undo/Redo are grayed out and the keyboard shortcuts don't work.  I can't work without an undo/redo.  (God only knows how many times these have pulled my butt out of the fire.)

All I can find for an undo setting is:

Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors-> Undo History size.

It was a value of 200, I tried changing it to 1000.

I have tried Google and here on Stack Overflow.  There is a similar question, but it wasn't how to enable the undo/redo.  This was a clean install of Eclipse.

Is there an enable check I am missing someplace buried in these option screens I am missing?

I am using the Java perspective with the 'classic' theme.

My java -version reports

```
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

What am I missing???

If there is no solution, and this is a bug (and a really bad one at that) can I use my old 3.7 with the above version of Java?  I am learning Java so I can write android apps, but I have not yet installed the SDKs yet.

Comment: did you disable them or was it from beginning disabled?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Juno Mobile - no problems here...

Comment: Try: Window -> Reset Perspective

Comment: sigh, I don't get it, today it is working... seriously, I have no idea what it was, I gave up yesterday mad at it, tried today, and ugh it's working.  Wish I had figured it out rather then this in case it happens again....

Comment: i have the same issue: approximately twice a month undo/redo in eclipse stops working. After restart it works again. i have aptana plugin installed.

Comment: I now also have the issue and restarting Eclipse twice did not solve it. I also have Aptana installed.

Comment: It might or might not have to do with it but updating PyDev helped … for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29949644/2961878     This is not the answer to your question, but I think AZURITE may help you manage undo/redo more efficiently in the future.

Answer (score 5):

First of all an apology, I know this reply does not answer this post original question.

I'm writing this here since this question was the 3rd result on google when I was searching for the phrase '*eclipse juno redo shortcut*', so, I thought it would be an OK place to answer that other question.

so, if you're looking for the keyboard shortcut for eclipse Juno redo function:

try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Eclipse solved this issue for me. Before restarting Undo and Redo were grayed out, and Ctrl-Z did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Kepler version, the default shortcut became ctrl + y.
You can change it to ctril + shift + z.
I have changed it back to ctril + shift + z.

Answer (score 0):

To change Redo shortcut: Windows -> Preferences -> Keys -> Search for "Redo"